# Upgraded Chromedriver to match Chrome version 74. Error says Chrome must be between 70-73

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

My Chrome browser has updated to `V74.0.3729.109`, and I have downloaded the new ChromeDriver, extracted it, and placed it in the `bin\debug` folder to replace the Chromedriver that was previously there.

I don't want to downgrade the browser (bad practice?). However, when I execute a test, I get this error:

> Message: OneTimeSetUp: System.InvalidOperationException : session not
>   created: Chrome version must be between 70 and 73   (Driver info:
>   chromedriver=2.45.615291
>   (ec3682e3c9061c10f26ea9e5cdcf3c53f3f74387),platform=Windows NT
>   10.0.17763 x86_64) (SessionNotCreated)

So it is not detecting the new driver. I tried removing the driver version several times.

Although marked as Duplicate the Duplicate question did not provide the answer, which is why I stated that "I have downloaded the new ChromeDriver". To correct answer is marked below.

Comment: If your `path` environment variable has a chromedriver, remove that and use  `System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "path to chromedriver.exe");` Then you would not have any confusion about the version of your chromedriver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have more than one chromedriver in your path. Try to find others using (at a command prompt):

```
where chromedriver
```

Comment: This was the correct answer. Thanks Lucas.